# Как решить проблему с внешним монитором?

Tags: macos, mac, apple, железо, монитор

Привет, помогите пожалуйста
Купил внешний монитор, подключаю ,работатет до полу часа и потом начинается снег. Что бы избавиться от снега, нужно вынимать монитор из розетки, вставлять обратно.
В 80% случаев монитор просто черный и не реагирует ни на что, но мышка с ноутбука на монитор перескакивает 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На винде включил - все работает стабильно, снега нет. Что делать?
Помогите, пожалуйста, очень беспокоюсь

Comment: Поясните вопрос, Какя модель монитора? каким переходником пользуетесь.

Comment: @DenisBubnov, вероятно, то, что на фото.

Comment: Думаю тут причин несколько. Первая, что приходит в голову - это обновления на маке. Была похожая фигня с телевизором пару месяцев назад, когда ноут бездействовал потом внешний экран не был активен. Ну и вторая идея - может в настройках монитора выставить настройку отключения или сохранения энергии.

Comment: @Akuma925 Вот ссылка на этот монитор на странице филипса -  http://www.p4c.philips.com/cgi-bin/dcbint/cpindex.pl?slg=ru&scy=ua&ctn=222E2SB/10<br>
Пользуюсь проводом HDMI и переходником с HDMI на DVI

Comment: @DenisBubnov И как решил?Я гуглил драйвера под эту модель - они только на windows 7, для mac OS их нет на сайте
<br>
Попробую, но я просматривал настройки и там не было похожей опции

Comment: У меня телевизор Samsung, на нем похожая хрень была - он как-то странно просыпался. Экран черный, а картинки нет. За это время у меня накатилось уже пару обновлений на систему, да еще и шнурок кажется поменял я на более дорогой.

Comment: @DenisBubnov аа, именно на ось обновления...нет, у меня последний капитан, шнурок недешевый взяд

Comment: подобный шум - очень похож на классический шум от dvi. Может переходник, может в самом разьеме проблема. И дорогой шнур - не панацея. Десять раз позолоченный hdmi кабель не улучшит своих характеристик, как бы того не утверждали аудиофилы.

Comment: Мне ваще показалось в начале что это перегрев карты, или с разьеомом что. Но рас на винде робит, может дровушки?

Comment: Как варианты решения проверить с другим монитором, проверить с другим переходником. Поставить последние обнавления.

Comment: к сожалению, железо - оффтопик на ruSO